# Splitting the sentences into new lines

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataset in this format:

```
The Da Vinci Code book is just awesome.1      this was the first clive cussler i've ever read, but even books like Relic, and Da Vinci code were more plausible than this.1      i liked the Da Vinci Code a lot.1     da vinci code was an awesome movie...1      the last stand and Mission Impossible 3 both were awesome movies.1     mission impossible 2 rocks!!....1     I love Harry Potter, but right now I hate it ( me younger sis's watching it ).1
```

They are separated by tab and they are not independent from each other, meaning in each line, there exists many sentences that each present a movie review.

My goal is to divide each sentence into a new line with that label (1 or 0, showing the negative/positive review). I used regular expression like this:

```
text_file = open('training.txt', 'r')
file = text_file.readlines()
s = []
for line in file:
    s.append(re.findall(r'\!*\.*\d+', line))

print(s)
```

However, the result was that it only showed the labels of each sentence, not what I was looking for. What I am looking for is like this:

```
The Da Vinci Code book is just awesome 1
this was the first clive cussler i've ever read, but even books like Relic, and Da Vinci code were more plausible than this 1
i liked the Da Vinci Code a lot 1
da vinci code was an awesome movie 1 
mission impossible 2 rocks 1
```

Or, any possible way suitable for classification, and working with pandas?

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: check this https://regex101.com/r/2r7SIv/1/ is this what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @CodeManiac Yes, exactly. Although, that $ sign is a bummer. I copied and pasted the code of regular expression, but all i had was list of empty lists.

Comment: @rashidi check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53994399/9624435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** (Code with Python Logic)
    Remove extra lists I have created; this is just a solution how to do it.

```
text_file = open('training.txt', 'r')  
file = text_file.readlines()  
s = []  
a = []  
b = []  

import re  

for line in file:  
    a = re.match(".*?[^\s][?=(1|0)]",line)  
    if a == None:  
        pass  
    else:  
        b = a.group()    
        s.append(b)  
print (s)
```

Data I used is as follows in the file. It will only grab review ending with 1 or 0 and add those sentences in the list.

dummy data
test data
wrong data for test
will add some correct data for test
The Da Vinci Code book is just awesome.1
this was the first clive cussler i've ever read, but even books like Relic, and Da Vinci code were more plausible than this.1
i liked the Da Vinci Code a lot.1       da vinci code was an awesome movie...1
the last stand and Mission Impossible 3 both were awesome movies.1
mission impossible 2 rocks!!....1
I love Harry Potter, but right now I hate it ( me younger sis's watching it ).1

**Result** 
[image: This is how list looks, list S]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did how you said. However, it returns a list of only labels, 1s and 0s... Not any text. I want to have text too so i can do training on them...

Comment: Sorry Rashidi, I misunderstood your reqt.
Here is the working solution. It will split now with 1 or 0 and you will get data too. You may have to trim spaces from the beginning or after 0 or 1. 

https://regex101.com/r/kPHOBg/2

Regex: '.*?[^\s][?=(1|0)]'

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your response.

Comment: To be honest, no. It works for someone with other pov, but not for me. However, i tackled the versions of regex in provided website (the other people did that too) and i came up with version 6 to be kind of what i want (with necessary edits). But, my point is to implement code wise rather than doing it like this. I copied/pasted the regex to my code, but no results...a list of epty lists. (in fact, i don't know what i am doing wrong. My code seems to not catch the whole sentence). So, i hold this post for a real implementation, because maybe it becomes other people's problem.

Comment: I am adding python code too. My list returns with all the data and number after them. You may have made some mistake in your code. I am not judging you, just making a guess. Check the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, i was making some mistakes in my code. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
(?<=\.)([0-1])\s*
```

- `(?<=\.)` - Positive lookbehind checks for `.`.
- `([01])` - Capturing group matches `0` or `1`.
- `\s*` - Matches space zero or more.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2r7SIv/6/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Not. It does not work for me. It returns a list of empty lists. Am i doing something wrong in reading the lines?

Comment: @rashidi python is not my major language so i would say just try printing file variable and see you're getting proper input or not.

Comment: It's weird. Inside the for loop, it shows prints what i exactly want, but when i do the re line, nothing happens (list of empty lists.) I even tried to put that variable inside for loop to a list, but again, at the end when i want to pritn it, nothing, literally nothing, happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import re
text_file = open('training.txt', 'r')
str_file = text_file.readlines()
p = re.compile("[ \t]{2,}")     # regex for 2 or more spaces
s = p.split(str_file[0])

print(s)
```

**Updated code** (using `readlines()` since the actual content/format of `training.txt` is not known):

```
import re
text_file = open('training.txt', 'r')
str_file = text_file.readlines()
p = re.compile("[ \t]{2,}")     # regex for 2 or more spaces
s = p.split(str_file[0])
print(s)
```

It's produce an `list` of `strings` like this:

```
['The Da Vinci Code book is just awesome.1', "this was the first clive cussler i've ever read, but even books like Relic, and Da Vinci code were more plausible than this.1", 'i liked the Da Vinci Code a lot.1', 'da vinci code was an awesome movie...1', 'the last stand and Mission Impossible 3 both were awesome movies.1', 'mission impossible 2 rocks!!....1', "I love Harry Potter, but right now I hate it ( me younger sis's watching it ).1"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, unfortunately, nothing is printing.

Comment: @rashidi Then what does `print(s)` prints? It should print the list.

Comment: You may not believe me, but it really does nothing. it does not print at all. I have no idea why.

Comment: Ok. I changed read() to readline() and this is what i got: ['ï»؟The Da Vinci Code book is just awesome.\n']

Comment: OK. I did. Apparently that s variable needs to be iterated rather than your way. I found out that if i do str_file[1], it will give the next value. And if i do other numbers, it will give other values from the file. Thank you for your response. It helped me a lot. However, the result is not clear. Take a look when at first 11 values:

Comment: [['ï»؟The Da Vinci Code book is just awesome.\n'], ["1\tthis was the first clive cussler i've ever read, but even books like Relic, and Da Vinci code were more plausible than this.\n"], ['1\ti liked the Da Vinci Code a lot.\n'], ['1\ti liked the Da Vinci Code a lot.\n'], ["1\tI liked the Da Vinci Code but it ultimatly didn't seem to hold it's own.\n"], ["1\tthat's not even an exaggeration ) and at midnight we went to Wal-Mart to buy the Da Vinci Code, which is amazing of course.\n"]] (I had to purge some values for limitation from stackoverflow.

Comment: How can i clear that up and know the length of p? Or how can i know the upper limit for iteration?